# Limit filter operators

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to limit the operators for views-filtering for users. I want them to only have "starts-with", "contains" and "same". But not the rest. Do I have to form_alter with a custom module? Or is there some intern way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to sort the exposed operators.

You can do it with a custom module using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter).

Example:

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'view_name') {
    unset($form['field_name_filter_op']['#options']['empty']);
    unset($form['field_name_filter_op']['#options']['not empty']);
  }

}
```

You can find the form details using "dpm()" from devel module.

- dpm($form_id);
- dpm($form);
- dpm($form_state);